# how to retrieve the related list by using python

Tags: python

Assume I have this:

```
[
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
```

and by searching name, I want to retrieve the related list: `["Tom", "Mark", "Pam"]`

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.get()` method to get the particular key's value. Alternatively, you can also, do `j['name']`

```
l1=[
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
l2=[j.get("name") for j in l1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value from a dict using list comprehension

```py
l = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
result = [d['key'] for d in l if 'key' in d]
```

In order to ensure that the we do not get a `KeyError`, we ensure that the dict actually has a key by that name, hence the `if 'key' in d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]

names = [detail['name'] for detail in lst]
ages = [detail['age'] for detail in lst]

print('Names:', names)
print('ages:', ages)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Names: ['Tom', 'Mark', 'Pam']
ages: [10, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

While in this case simple `[d['name'] for d in l]` will work. I wanted to introduce itemgetter, where you can get multiple keys at once in single comprehension

```py
from operator import itemgetter

l = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
name = list(map(itemgetter('name'), l))
# ['Tom', 'Mark', 'Pam']
# multiple keys, useful when you want to sort dict with lots of keys by name and age
name, age = zip(*map(itemgetter('name', 'age'), l))
# get name and age as separate tuples
```